# FragmentDialog setMultiChoiceItems covers below views

Tags: android-studio, android-dialogfragment

I'm making a DialogFragment and I want to show a multichoiceitems (builder.setMultiChoiceItems) and a positive button (builder.setPositiveButton) at the bottom, the problem is that when there are too many items in the setMultiChoiceItems the bottom views are covered by them.

I think that I have to set a maximum height for the setMultichoiceItems but I can't figure out how.

Here is my code inside DialogFragment class:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.orderActivityContext);
    final ArrayList<String> variants = getArguments().getStringArrayList("variants");
    final String[] variantsArray = new String[variants.size()];
    final boolean[] checkedVariants = new boolean[variants.size()];
    //Mostra le varianti con collegate una checkBox
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(variants.toArray(variantsArray), checkedVariants, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i, boolean isChecked) {
            //Imposta a true le checkedVariants checkate
            checkedVariants[i] = isChecked;
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            /*MY CODE*/
        }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
```

Here as it is with just a few items:

[image: Here as it is with just a few items]

Here as it is with a lot of items:

[image]